# What should be login related links called

Tags: login, terminology

We need to group login related links together under one header.

Links

1. Login/Sign In
2. Forgot Password
3. Register/Sign Up
4. etc.

We need the word for this "Header".

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that we are making a document where we need a header for these links.

We don't need the term/word to put on actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically group these under either:

- **"Account"**, or
- **"Authorization"**

Login/Sign in, Forgot PW, and Registering all involve authorizing a person to take action on your site, and likewise, they all involve actions pertinent to a user's account.

And mind you, I am assuming these terms (especially "Authorization") do not need to be user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple plain message like **Welcome to Productname** or just **Welcome**.
If its a funky sort of site that can allow unusual header then you can try keywords like **Jump In** or **Hop In** or **Dive In**

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon factors, Who are the target audiences?, What are their age group?, Why are you making this website? ...

So lets say this is just a social website:

it can be used:

1: **Let's Get Started!**

2: **Get In**

3: **Get Connected**
...

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot decide, then why not run an A/B Testing on the text to see which one works best for your website? A few people have given good options, but all very different, so a test is probably worthwhile.